# Hot water tank no longer getting hot after bathroom refit

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I wanted a little advice. I’ve just had my bathroom redone; and the fitter/plumber has now left saying “nothing he can do” seek help elsewhere.

The problem: No hot water in any tap; but radiators are hot.

Example of the pipe work is below. The fitter/plumber installed a new pump for the shower (spurring the hot water from the head valve on the hot water tank). Note: This is a gravity fed system.

[image]

What we’ve got is that the hot water is flowing through the outflow on the boiler (it’s getting the radiators) but not to the hot water tank.

Focusing on the tank itself. The head outflow is cold (or lukewarm at best) but the inlet pipe, the middle pipe is hot, but the lowest pipe is stone cold.

I wanted to ask for some suggestions on debugging. My initial thoughts could be that it is the divert value to the left; but I don’t want to be just changing items for the sake of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the heater is working, I would suspect a valve was not turned back after the work.

Comment: This guy does uk gravity systems his video does a good job of explaining how to troubleshoot.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXXILH-1lwU

Comment: I would tell the plumber that the rest of his payment is withheld until he gets hot water flowing at the taps and that if it takes too long, you'll be letting the licensing board know about his work quality and ethic. Sheesh!

Comment: On the above. ~crip659 checked all valves. Everything seems on; unless a value is broken. Thanks @Fresh Codemonger will take a look. 

~FreeMan. Payment is being withheld. He has she this hands of it. Sadly in the UK, bathroom fitters/plumers are not licensed unless they interface with the gas.